# PartialResultException when authenticating over LDAP with Acegi and Grails

Tags: grails, ldap, spring-security

I'm trying to setup our new Grails application to authenticate via LDAP. From the logs we can see that Acegi is binding to the LDAP store, then is able to find the user given the correct credentials, and finally begins searching for roles.

The authentication fails due to a PartialResultException.

I'm aware that the default LDAP provider in Acegi has an option to ignore PartialResultExceptions, but I'm not exactly sure how to turn that on in Grails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem at the [SpringSource forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showpost.php?p=52396&postcount=19)

Basically I needed to be more specific with the Group Search Base. Adding in a more specific OU fixed the problem.